# QuickPDF library for converting local html pages to pdf

Tags: c#

I want to use QUICKPDF library in my C# windows form project. I want to convert the local HTMl pages to PDF . Is it possible to convert 'local html' pages using quickpdf dll.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of converting html to pdf using quickpdf

```
// Setup the parameters
string fileName = "C:\\example.pdf";
string licenseKey = "...";

// Create the library
QuickPDFAX0712.PDFLibrary qp = new QuickPDFAX0712.PDFLibrary();

// Unlock the library
qp.UnlockKey(licenseKey);
qp.DrawHTMLText(40, 760, 200, "Here is some <b>bold</b>, <i>italic</i> and <u>underlined</u> text");
qp.DrawHTMLText(40, 730, 200, "<ul><li>This</li><li>is</li><li>a</li><li>bullet</li><li>list</li></ul>");

// Save the new PDF that you've created.
qp.SaveToFile(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use this library

http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/Default.aspx